# Cannot mount newly created Logical Volume

Tags: rhel, mount, lvm

I try to create a Logical Volume under an existing Volume Group but I cannot mount the new LV due to error: "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open":

```
[root@host-xxxx ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_redhat601-LogVol00
                       29G  4.5G   23G  17% /
tmpfs                  16G   72K   16G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/vda5             190M   38M  143M  21% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_redhat6-LogVol00
                       33G   48M   31G   1% /AMS

[root@host-xxxx ~]# vgdisplay vg_redhat6
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_redhat6
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               70.96 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              18167
  Alloc PE / Size       8448 / 33.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       9719 / 37.96 GiB
  VG UUID               6YbIIs-OBJe-PGyV-Pwsl-VLGX-Jrf2-1SgJUZ
```

As can be seen above, there is 37.96G free space under the vg_redhat6 VG. Thus, I decided to create a LV with the size of 15G:

```
[root@host-xxxx ~]# lvcreate -L 15G -n LogVol01 vg_redhat6
  Logical volume "LogVol01" created.

[root@host-xxxx ~]# lvdisplay /dev/vg_redhat6/LogVol01
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_redhat6/LogVol01
  LV Name                LogVol01
  VG Name                vg_redhat6
  LV UUID                2FWKKM-mcbQ-RoCk-H2jc-0Jbt-nuha-KqYGtX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time host-135-249-45-28, 2016-04-08 14:44:00 +0530
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                15.00 GiB
  Current LE             3840
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:3
```

When I run e2fsck on the related LV, I see following error:

```
[root@host-xxxx ~]# e2fsck /dev/vg_redhat6/LogVol01 e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010) e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks... e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/vg_redhat6/LogVol01

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2 filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

Due to the above error, I cannot mount this new LV. I did some search on Google but could not find any useful recommendation.
Did you face with this problem before? Do you have any idea how to get over this problem?

Comment: Did you make a file system on the new logical volume?  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/make_mount_ex3.html

Comment: After doing so I could mount the LV. However, the server does not come up after rebooting the server :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a volume — an empty space where information can be stored. You can't mount it, because what gets mounted is a [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem) — a structure for information. Mounting makes a filesystem visible in a directory.

Use the appropriate `mkfs` command to create a filesystem on the volume, e.g. to create an ext4 filesystem (the de facto standard on Linux) run (as root) `mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg_redhat6/LogVol01`